How to make an operator not undoable?
I'd like to make an addon to do view3d.camera_flip_x() but not make any undo history, because Clip Studio Paint doesn't include flipping in the undo history and it's annoying to draw on blender when I have a habit of flipping a lot to check drawings from a different perspective.

You would make an operator, then in the bl_options you would make sure it doesn't have "UNDO". Open the scripting window and then go to Template > Operator Add Mesh and you should see bl_idname, bl_label, bl_options etc. bl_options has {REGISTER, UNDO} that would be where that kind of stuff is in an operator.

When I tried this already, I never even wrote undo, but it still has it there in the history. Is it because I'm doing view3d.camera_flip_x? If I had to guess, that operator I called is what is actually being added, instead of my operator

I don't think that's possible. I think this kind of functionality is not desirable and the devs would try to avoid this in the API. But I am not 100% sure...

I'm looking into using on-release keymaps for the actual flip operator, and temporarily disabling global undo with the press. I'll post an answer here if I get it working, hopefully with a huge warning that it's really bad form.

Nevermind, can't be done, waiting in a modal would just eat all release inputs and not let the release key hear it.

plus even in global undo mode off, it still ends up in the undo stack, just merged with the action which came after.

Hello and welcome. Can you share a simple example of an operator exhibiting this behavior?

after disabling global undo, try flipping the camera, then re enabling Global Undo, and drawing a stroke (gpencil.draw), and undoing will undo both at once.
